# Prevent json_encode associative array sorting

Tags: php, associative-array, json

I have a associative array

```
Array(
   [289] => Array(
    'name'=> 'One'
   ),
   [292] => Array(
    'name'=> 'One'
   ),
   [290] => Array(
    'name'=> 'One'
   )
)
```

After i use json_encode on this array. The keys are sorted, although i get it as JSON object.

Is there way to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Looks like php json_encode is return the correct order. Its the browser which is sorting the object.

Comment: Are you sure?  For me PHP's json_encode sorts the array, rather than the browsers.

Comment: Check out JSON_FORCE_OBJECT in  http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php - I had an associative array with numeric ID's as the keys and it was converting them as a non-associative array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> there is no standard that says it has to be in a certain order.

See this for a related question: [How do you stop Chrome and Opera sorting JSON objects by Index ASC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020699/how-do-you-stop-chrome-and-opera-sorting-json-objects-by-index-asc)

*note: we're talking about a PHP function, but the result is basically javascript, so the statement about the non-existing standard applies as well.*

btw: I have tested it with the following code. PHP itself doesnt seem to sort the array, firefox doesn't as well (according to the firebug console).

```
<pre>
<?php
    $array = array();
    $array[289] = array('name'=>'One');
    $array[292] = array('name'=>'One');
    $array[290] = array('name'=>'One');
    print_r($array);
    $string = json_encode($array);
    print_r($string);
?>
</pre>
<script>
    var foo = <?=$string?>;
    console.log(foo);
</script>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you want your own order, give the array your own index.

Comment: +1 , for the right thing.

Comment: Yes, its browser which is culprit

Comment: Note: firefox will sort keys if the keys are numeric and under something like 500.  Javascript objects are not guaranteed to have ordering, this is a mistake a lot of people, most languages associative arrays are not ordered by entry.  If you want order, use ordered arrays. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=865760

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
    $ar = array();
    $ar[1] = array('1'=>'one');
    $ar[2] = array('2'=>'two');
    $ar[3] = array('3'=>'three');
    print_r($ar);
    $str= json_encode($ar);
    print_r($str);
```

it should work, at-least helps me !

Comment: It doesn't work like that, i have a non associative array where i need to preserve the keys but order alphabetichally by Value, using Asort it gets ordered properly but when sent to using json_encode the object gets sorted by key again

Comment: That's exactly the same problem I'm having, been looking for a solution everywhere but no luck yet.