# sorting doesn't work in laravel http response

Tags: php, sorting, laravel-5

When I try to do `asort($data)` and then return it like `response()->json($data, 200)`, the output is still in its original position.

Here's the code:

```
$fruits = array( 'guava', 'apple', 'orange' );
asort( $fruits );
return response()->json( $fruits, 200 );
```

then the output is still in its position.

```
{
  0: "guava",
  1: "apple",
  2: "orange"
}
```

But when I try to dump the data just after the sorting happen, like

```
$fruits = array( 'guava', 'apple', 'orange' );
asort( $fruits );
dd( $fruits );
```

I'm getting the right position of data.

```
array:3 [
  1 => "apple"
  0 => "guava"
  2 => "orange"
]
```

Any idea, why this happen? and how can I solve this?
Im using **Laravel 5.1**

Comment: Have you tried `return response()->json( $fruits );` without the status 200?

Comment: Yes, its still doesn't work.

Comment: if everything fails try `return json_encode( $fruits);`

Comment: @pinkalvansia, that is exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you can have an array with numerical index out of order in php is purely a php thing.

The json output shouldn't care about that.. it's possible that `json_encode` is called on the fly, or that what you're seeing is simply an optimisation from the browser (it is an object `{}`).

See this SO question that has some valuable input regarding this: [Prevent json_encode associative array sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216391/prevent-json-encode-associative-array-sorting).

*However* in your context, unless you really care about the index, `asort` is probably not what you want. You want `sort`.

**Edit** if you want to maintain both order and key assoc, you need to change the structure to an array of object `{key,value}`

**Edit 2** you can reduce your array to that structure like this (php 5.4+):

```
$fruits = array_map(function($index,$value) {
        return ['index'=>$index,'value'=>$value];
    },array_keys($fruits),$fruits);
```

Comment: I need "asort()" because I need to "maintain key association".

Comment: Yes, you're right but that's a different structure.

Comment: @kjames. Yes, that's correct. What you're trying to do is only applicable in php, not json. You'll need to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it, the problem is that your JSON response will sort the array by keys.  Since you maintain index association with `asort()`, that array isn't really sorted according to JSON.  Use `sort()` instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: Okay, but I need to "maintain key association" that's why I cannot use "sort()".