# php json - Issue display in returned array order (json sort)

Tags: php, jquery, json, select, append

**Intro:**

I have 2 dropdowns. The second drop down is loaded via json (`json_display.php`) based on the value of first drop down (`index.html`). I have used json - `append()` to load inside drop down.

**Question:**

The json append() to dropdown always in ascending order of array keys. Expected result is to display in the format whatever array order `json_display.php` returns.

- I have alert jquery `theResponse`, shows wrong sort order.
- I have tried with the array key as integer and string, In both cases also the output is same.

**Note:**

*(Actually I was trying to retrieve mysqli rows with descending order of date and store `id => name` in the array and return)*

For simplicity, I have extracted the problem part of code to `index.html` and `json_display.php` which were a part of bigger coding. Also changed the mysql retrievals to arrays. The names and all values are changed for explanation purposes.

> **Graphical Explanation**

[image: Graphical Representation]

---

> **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#frm").on('change', ' #first_select_box', function(){
        var $this    = $(this);
        var this_val = $this.val();

        $('#second_select_box option').not(':eq(0)').remove();

        $.ajax({
            type     : "POST",
            url      : "json_display.php",
            data     : { first_select_id: this_val },
            dataType : 'json',
            success  : function(theResponse) {

                //alert(JSON.stringify(theResponse));

                $.each(theResponse, function(key, value) {
                    $('#second_select_box')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",key)
                    .text(value));
                });
            }

        });

    });
}); 
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form id="frm" name="frm" method="post" action="#a">

<select id="first_select_box" name="first_select_box">
<option value="0">[First Drop Down]</option>
<option value="1">Numbers</option>
<option value="2">Fruits</option>
<option value="3">Teens</option>
</select>

<select id="second_select_box" name="second_select_box">
<option value="0">[Select]</option>
</select>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

> **json_display.php**

```
<?php
$Array[0] = array();
$Array[1] = array(10 => 'Ten', 
                  9  => 'Nine', 
                  8  => 'Eight', 
                  7  => 'Seven', 
                  6  => 'Six', 
                  5  => 'Five', 
                  4  => 'Four'
                  );

$Array[2] = array(8 => 'Apple', 
                  1 => 'Orange', 
                  3 => 'Banana', 
                  2 => 'Watermelon', 
                  7 => 'Lemon'
                  );

$Array[3] = array(17 => 'Seventeen', 
                  11 => 'Eleven', 
                  13 => 'Thirteen', 
                  15 => 'Fifteen', 
                  12 => 'Twelve', 
                  14 => 'Fourteen', 
                  16 => 'Sixteen'
                  );

$first_select_id      = isset($_POST['first_select_id']) ? $_POST['first_select_id'] : 0;

$return_array = $Array[$first_select_id];

echo json_encode($return_array);

?>
```

Comment: and the question is ?????

Comment: It is the behaviour of javascript in browser, can you pass the key (value) as string identifier instead? That would maintain the order

Comment: @Thamizhan Did you mean the key as string, I have tried that also.

Comment: @Devs Yes.. try appending a character to it like `D1` or `@1`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem.  My C# application allows the user to override the default sort order of a list of values in a table, so the data passed back to the javascript is not necessarily in alphabetical or numerical order.  The data was in the correct order when it left my MVC controller action, but when inspecting the response returned to the browser the list had had been sorted by the numeric key.

Since I needed my select list options to be in the order specified by my user,  I tried adding a space to the beginning of my key as recommended by Thamilan, but unfortunately that did not work. Just adding any old character would also not work, since it would still sort it according to alphanumeric sorting rules, and I didn't want it getting sorted at ALL.

So instead I added a counter to the loop that adds to the list being returned to the browser, and pre-pended the value of the counter with a "." to my key as it was being added to the list, so that my returned list looked like this when  returned to the browser:

[image: sample data returned from controller]

This ensured that the alphanumeric sorting would always be in the order I purposely created.  So all I had to do in the javascript was extract out the correct key value for the options list as required by my application.  To do this I simply removed the prefixing counter and "." from my key using split:

```
var optionValue = xhrKey.split(".")[1];
```

The resulting select list was in the same order as that returned from my controller, and with the correct value assigned to the options in the select list.

Answer (score 1):

It display correct as `json_display.php` send to `index.html`. `json_display.php` sending indexed array hence it displayed correctly. For example look at your first index of `$Array`

```
$Array[1] = array(10 => 'Ten', 
                  9  => 'Nine', 
                  8  => 'Eight', 
                  7  => 'Seven', 
                  6  => 'Six', 
                  5  => 'Five', 
                  4  => 'Four'
                  );
```

It means that `10th` index of `$Array[1]` will have `Ten` value and so on. So when it comes to the JS it already indexed and will display `Four` as first option and `Ten` as last option. You will need to wrap the array key in quotes. So taking your example your array should be converted like this

```
$Array[1] = array('10' => 'Ten', 
                  '9'  => 'Nine', 
                  '8'  => 'Eight', 
                  '7'  => 'Seven', 
                  '6'  => 'Six', 
                  '5'  => 'Five', 
                  '4'  => 'Four'
                  );
```

This should solve the problem with order you are having. Hope that helps.

Updates:

Since all browser still index array numeric keys, only option IMO is to send proper indexed array. For example php should send back the array in the following format

```
Array[1] = array(0 =>array("key"=>10, "value"=> 'Ten'), 
                  1 =>array("key"=>9, "value"=> 'Nine'),
                  2 =>array("key"=>8, "value"=> 'Eigth'),
                  3 =>array("key"=>7, "value"=> 'Seven'),
                  4 =>array("key"=>6, "value"=> 'Size'),
                  5 =>array("key"=>5, "value"=> 'Five'),
                  6 =>array("key"=>4, "value"=> 'Four'),
                  );
```

Then in index.html you need to modify the response code to.

```
$.each(theResponse, function( index, obj ) {
                $('#second_select_box')
                .append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value",obj.key)
                .text(obj.value));
            });
```

This might help 
[How do you stop Chrome and Opera sorting JSON objects by Index ASC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020699/how-do-you-stop-chrome-and-opera-sorting-json-objects-by-index-asc)

Comment: I have already tried with the array key as string, The result was same.

Comment: @Devs OK, I tested and it seems browser still index it if numeric keys are in quotes, so only option is to update the array with proper indexing In my opinion. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Append the keys with a space before sending them to browser. This json won't be sorted now.
Its a default behavior that in whatever order you send your data, the keys are sorted. But if they are given as string by appending space before the keys, they won't be sorted.

Comment: That would be a good suggestion. It would be appreciated if could do any other possibility rather than changing the `id` as its the dynamic unique id from database.

Answer (score 1):

The required result can obtain with bellow code,but i am not sure is there a better way.

**json_display.php**

```
<?php
$Array[0] = array();
$Array[1] = array(10 => 'Ten', 
                  9  => 'Nine', 
                  8  => 'Eight', 
                  7  => 'Seven', 
                  6  => 'Six', 
                  5  => 'Five', 
                  4  => 'Four'
                  );

$Array[2] = array(8 => 'Apple', 
                  1 => 'Orange', 
                  3 => 'Banana', 
                  2 => 'Watermelon', 
                  7 => 'Lemon'
                  );

$Array[3] = array(17 => 'Seventeen', 
                  11 => 'Eleven', 
                  13 => 'Thirteen', 
                  15 => 'Fifteen', 
                  12 => 'Twelve', 
                  14 => 'Fourteen', 
                  16 => 'Sixteen'
                  );

$first_select_id      = isset($_POST['first_select_id']) ? $_POST['first_select_id'] : 0;

$return_array_temp = $Array[$first_select_id];
$return_array = array();
foreach ($return_array_temp as $key => $value) {
    $return_array[$key." "] = $value;
}
echo json_encode($return_array);

?>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#frm").on('change', ' #first_select_box', function(){
        var $this    = $(this);
        var this_val = $this.val();

        $('#second_select_box option').not(':eq(0)').remove();

        $.ajax({
            type     : "POST",
            url      : "json_display.php",
            data     : { first_select_id: this_val },
            dataType : 'json',
            success  : function(theResponse) {

                //alert(JSON.stringify(theResponse));

                $.each(theResponse, function(key, value) {
                    $('#second_select_box')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",key.trim())
                    .text(value));
                });
            }

        });

    });
}); 
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form id="frm" name="frm" method="post" action="#a">

<select id="first_select_box" name="first_select_box">
<option value="0">[First Drop Down]</option>
<option value="1">Numbers</option>
<option value="2">Fruits</option>
<option value="3">Teens</option>
</select>

<select id="second_select_box" name="second_select_box">
<option value="0">[Select]</option>
</select>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This won't work because browser still index it in ascending order as the keys are numeric. No matter if you wrap then in quotes.

Comment: @Devs I have updated my answer,this may help your problem

Answer (score 0):

Use **array_flip()** function to exchange key-value in array

change

```
echo json_encode($return_array);
```

to

```
echo json_encode(array_flip($return_array));
```

and you will get result as expected.

Comment: array_flip() is to swap keys with the value. The issue is no in array flipping. its the jquery which automatically sort the key in ascending order of `theResponse`